# bind_param does not save special characters correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, bind, param

I need to use bind_param to get away with data injection. When I use bind_param, special characters such as € or ب are being saved in mysql as ØµØ°Ù‚.

1-I am sure mysql table is set up correctly.

2-I have changed the word processor's encoding to UTF8.

3-I have included many utf8 character sets all over the place.

Any thoughts how to fix this? or maybe I should start using other methods such as mysqli_real_escape_string?

($_POST["post_word"] is generated in a separate page)

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("r"," r","r","r");  //not real data here
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
$connect->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$querye= mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO wordtable ( wdate) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())");

$sqlz = "SELECT wid FROM wordtable ORDER BY  wdate DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultz = mysql_query($sqlz);
$rowz = mysql_fetch_array($resultz);
$wid=$rowz['wid'];

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["post_word"];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE wordtable SET  word=(?)
                            WHERE wid='$wid' ");
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $unsafe_variable);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: How exactly do you confirm that the data is inserted incorrectly? Encodings are a two-way street. The sender has to send correctly and the receiver has to receive/interpret correctly. We're only seeing the input, yet you propose that the output is incorrect.

Comment: @deceze because when I use the regular INSERT, the data is stored correctly. So I assume there is something messed up with bind_param.

Comment: There may also be something messed up with your insert *and* output, only your update is correct. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for maybe some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be perhaps

`$querye= mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Your querying with MySQL here

Comment: I changed it to $querye= mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8"); still no success